# JUnit on failure callback/method

Tags: unit-testing, junit, callback, annotations, handler

Is there any possibility to trigger a method whenever a testcase or assertion fails, in order to do some things when a testcase fails (e.g. Screenshot while UI-Testing, writing an error log, and so on...).

Maybe there is something like an annotation, I did not yet notice.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `TestWatcher` rule and implement your own `failed` method to take a screenshot or whatever you need to do upon test failure. Slightly modified example from the [official documentation](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/TestWatcher.html):

```java
public static class WatchmanTest {
    private static String watchedLog;

    @Rule
    public TestRule watchman = new TestWatcher() {
        @Override
        protected void failed(Throwable e, Description description) {
            watchedLog += d + "\n";
            // take screenshot, etc.
        }
    };

    @Test
    public void fails() {
        fail();
    }
}
```

Comment: A problem occured here: I need a method that is triggered BEFORE any `@After` annotated method is called. Is there any possibility to achieve this?