# Perform action if Maven / Cucumber test fails?

Tags: java, maven, cucumber

I have a set of cucumber tests ran in Maven job.  How would I perform a specific action if the test fails?

RunnerTest.Java

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@Cucumber.Options(format = {"html:target/test-report", "json:target/test-report.json", "junit:target/test-report.xml"}, 
features = "src/test/resource"
)
public class RunnerTest {
}
```

Comment: Please explain, what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the TestWatcher rule.
More information here : [JUnit on failure callback/method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19956955/junit-on-failure-callback-method)